# SQL Server : Json Column Query/Select Based On Value Within Json Array

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a column that has the following JSON in it (this is a small sample, there are a lot of other rows).

```
[
    { "Key": "priorityProduct", "Value": "0" },
    { "Key": "somethingElse", "Value": "another value" },
    { "Key": "remove", "Value": "1" },
    { "Key": "anotherHere", "Value": "27" }
]
```

I want to `SELECT` the value of the `remove` only in a SQL query and ignore the other values. So I could SELECT some SQL columns to say `name`, `address` and use something like this to fill the `remove`?

```
SELECT 
    [name], address, 
    JSON_VALUE(MyColumn, '$[Key:"remove"].Value') AS Remove
```

Does such a query syntax exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON data in the question is a JSON array, so you need to parse this JSON with `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   JsonData nvarchar(max),
   [Name] nvarchar(100), 
   Address nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO Data (
   JsonData, [Name], [Address])
VALUES (
   N'[
{"Key":"priorityProduct","Value":"0"},
{"Key":"somethingElse","Value":"another value"},
{"Key":"remove","Value":"1"},
{"Key":"anotherHere","Value":"27"}
]', N'Name', N'Address')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.[Name], d.[Address], j.[Value] AS [Remove]
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.JsonData) WITH (
   [Key] nvarchar(100) '$.Key',
   [Value] nvarchar(100) '$.Value'
) j
WHERE j.[Key] = N'remove'
```

Result:

```
----------------------
Name    Address Remove
----------------------
Name    Address 1
```

If you want to use `JSON_VALUE()`, the next statement may help. Note, that `JSON_VALUE()` returns a single text value of type `nvarchar(4000)`:

```
SELECT d.[Name], d.[Address], JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.Value') AS [Remove]
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.JsonData) j
WHERE JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.Key') = N'remove'
```

Of course, if this JSON has a fixed structure and `remove` key is always at 3rd position, you may use something like this:

```
SELECT [Name], [Address], JSON_VALUE(JsonData, '$[2].Value') AS [Remove]
FROM Data
```